# DCC model implementation in "rmgarch" package

Tags: r, time-series, garch

The fitting procedure of Dynamic Conditional Correlation (DCC) model requires a first stage estimation procedure of univariate models on each time series. Then this vector with the best estimates is used to go on with the second step procedure and calculate the remaining parameters.

My questions here is, does the "rmgarch" package work like this? Comparing univariate models before providing DCC estimates automatically? Or do we somehow provide the model with a vector of the best estimated standard deviations?

Example:
Assume that I have a dataset of three assets and the best fitted univariate models are the GARCH, EGARCH and CSGARCH, respectively, with estimates of standard deviation sd1, sd2, sd3. How could this be taken into account in the DCC procedure?

Comment: What do you mean by "Comparing univariate models before providing DCC estimates automatically?" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"rmgarch" does indeed estimate the DCC model in two steps (using function `dccfit`) and it requires

1. either univariate GARCH specifications (argument `uspec` in function `dccspec`, the result of which is used in function `dccfit`)
2. or fitted univariate GARCH models (argument `fit` in function `dccfit`)

as an input. If you already have estimated some univariate GARCH models and do not want to reestimate them so as to save computational time, perhaps you could restrict the parameter values at their estimated values from before when using the function `multispec` (which you will have to use anyway to create an argument to be submitted either to `dccspec` or `multifit`).

Comment: Dear @Richard Hardy, I hope you are doing well. Is there a way to estimate the DCC model solely based on the filtered standardized residuals which were obtained from a Markov regime-switching GARCH model in R? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @BlgKhalil, I am not sure. Perhaps it is possible to cheat by specifying DCC-GARCH for the filtered standardized residuals and restricting the GARCH parameters to be $\alpha=0.001$ and $\beta=0.999$ so that the conditional variance is approximately constant. (You want it to be exactly constant, but I don't now how to do that.)